# apache mod_proxy cluster with websockets and http

Tags: apache, http, websocket, cluster-computing, mod-proxy

I have

1. apache 2.4.10 192.168.0.10
2. jboss8 node1 192.168.0.20 - in domain mode
3. jboss8 node2 192.168.0.21 - in slave mode -

I trying create cluster via mod_proxy http://192.168.0.10/myapp with http and websocket connections

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cluster1
ServerName 192.168.0.10
ErrorLog logs/cluster1_log_error
CustomLog logs/cluster1_log_comm common
TransferLog logs/cluster1_log_trans

Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://jboss>
    BalancerMember   ws://192.168.0.21:8080 route=2
    BalancerMember http://192.168.0.21:8080 route=2
    BalancerMember   ws://192.168.0.20:8080 route=1
    BalancerMember http://192.168.0.20:8080 route=1
    ProxySet  stickysession=ROUTEID
    ProxySet nofailover=off
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /myapp balancer://jboss/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp balancer://jboss/myapp


<Location /mcm>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>
```

but If I disable workers ws and http for jboss2 via balancer manager - 
traffic still sending to node

how to do it right ? 
two balancers ?
one balancer ?
I need help